# In print statements, what determines whether python shell prints null character or waits for input

Tags: python

Recently I was trying some practice programs in python and I came across this small problem.

when I typed

```
print ""
```

in IDLE, the python shell printed a null character.

If I typed

```
print """"""
```

in IDLE, the python shell printed a null character.

but the python shell waits for input if I type

```
print """"
```

Why is this behaviour observed. As far as my knowledge goes, it should print null character for this `print """"` also.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In python you can have strings enclosed with either 1 or 3 quotes.

```
print "a"
print """a"""
```

In your case, the interpreter is waiting for the last triple quote.

Comment: And quotes can be " or ' (but the same on each side)

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you mean that python printed an empty line -- this is not the same as a null character.

When you `print """"""`, python finds an empty, triple-quoted string.

When you `print """"`, python finds the start of a triple-quoted string, and waits for you to input the rest (ending with `"""`).

A triple-qouted string can include other qoutes, linebreaks, etc.